# Gulp Series Tasks not running after gulp connect

Tags: javascript, node.js, gulp

I'm trying to run the following gulp tasks in series:

**Open->Connect->Watch**

Following is my gulpfile:

```
"use strict";

var gulp = require('gulp');
var connect = require('gulp-connect'); 
var open = require('gulp-open'); 

var config = {
    port: 9005,
    devBaseUrl: 'http://localhost',
    paths: {
        html: './src/*.html',
        dist: './dist'
    }
}

gulp.task('connect', function() {
    connect.server({
        root: 'dist',
        port: config.port,
        base: config.devBaseUrl,
        livereload: true
    })
});

gulp.task('open', gulp.series('connect'), function(){
    gulp.src('dist/index.html')
        .pipe(open({uri: config.devBaseUrl + ':' + config.port + '/'}));
});

gulp.task('html', function(){
    gulp.src(config.paths.html)
        .pipe(gulp.dest(config.paths.dist))
        .pipe(connect.reload());
});

gulp.task('watch', function(){
    gulp.watch(config.paths.html, ['html']);
});

gulp.task('default', gulp.series('open', 'watch'));
```

By running gulp from the command line (Using powershell in Windows 10), I get the following output:

```
Starting 'default'...
[17:42:37] Starting 'open'...
[17:42:37] Starting 'connect'...
[17:42:37] Starting server...
[17:42:37] Server started http://localhost:9005
[17:42:37] Running server
```

The **Watch** task never gets triggered. This seems to be an issue in the **Connect** task, as **Open** was able to trigger **Connect** in series.

Would be grateful for some help.

Comment: I think since you’re defining watch and open as series, it waits for open to complete to run ‘watch’. Since you will want to keep both task running at the same time, in your default try gulp.parallel instead

Comment: Thanks, I was referencing gulp 3 docs and using gulp 4. Got the issue.

Comment: Cool! If you can, perhaps answer your own question & mark it as close.

Comment: If you're using Gulp 4, please take another look at the documentation as a lot of has changed.

Specifically look at the section about creating tasks. Each task function must either return one of a few types of values, or call the callback provided by Gulp.